# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the following SQL error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
>       that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the 
>       right syntax to use near `` `classxii`.`email`='rajdeep@gmail.com', `classx`.`email`='rajdeep@gmail.com' `` at line 5

My PHP code looks like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `graduation`, `classxii`, `classx` SET `university`='$university', `college`='$college', `course`='$course', `branch`='$branch', `year`='$year', 
`school1`='$school1', `board1`='$board1', `percentage1`='$percentage1', `year1`='$year1', 
`school2`='$school2', `board2`='$board2', `percentage2`='$percentage2', `year2`='$year2' 
WHERE `graduation`.`email`='$email', `classxii`.`email`='$email', `classx`.`email`='$email'";

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Multiple `WHERE`  conditions are combined using AND/OR, not simply a comma separated list of conditions

Comment: Now stop using the old, deprecated mysql extension; and switch to mysqli or pdo with prepared statements and bind variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change commas to AND in your where part of the statement:

```
WHERE `graduation`.`email`='$email' AND `classxii`.`email`='$email' AND `classx`.`email`='$email'";
```

Or if searching only one of them use OR:

```
WHERE `graduation`.`email`='$email' OR `classxii`.`email`='$email' OR `classx`.`email`='$email'";
```